# ConcurrentModificationException in foreach loop even though I don't remove anything from arraylist

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, foreach

I know there are similar questions, but I went through them and didn't find an answer.

My code is single threaded, it isn't removing anything or anyhow modifying the arraylist during the loop, just adding.

CODE:

```
ArrayList<Record> records = helper.get();
System.out.println("Records in arraylist: " + records.size());
    for (Record x : records) {
        System.out.println("Begin");
        Record record = new Record(many parameters);
        System.out.println("Middle");
        records.add(record);
        System.out.println("End");
    }
    System.out.println("Done reading records and inserting them to arrayList");
```

Output:

```
Records in arraylist: 1000
Begin
Middle
End
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:33)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 records.add(record);
```

You modified the ArrayList this line.

You can turn your for-each loop to indexed-for loop to prevent `ConcurrentModificationException`, or maybe you can just create a new `ArrayList` to hold your records:

```
ArrayList<Record> records = helper.get();
ArrayList<Record> result = new ArrayList<Record>();
for (Record x : records) {
    Record record = new Record(many parameters);
    result.add(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 records.add(record);
```

Here you modify your array.